# How can we get billing plan id, once the payment complete in paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I need billing plan id, after the payment in paypal, i have billing agreeement id, but i am not able to get plan id based on agreement id,  Is there any way with that we can get the billing plan id ?

Answer (score 0):

Returning the Billing Plan ID in the Get Billing agreement details response is currently not supported. The created Billing Agreement ID does not contain any reference back to the originating plan at this time. The Billing Agreement simply contains its own plan object that is created using the properties from the original Billing Plan ID.

You can reference the issue at the link below as an Improvement was filed to try and get this functionality added to the Get Billing Agreement response.

***Note:***
There is also somewhat of a workaround explained at the link below which states how to get the Billing Plan ID in the meantime.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/92